# Asian film from about 15 years ago where protagonist can mimic and hide in someone's shadow perfectly

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a captivating Asian film roughly around 2009 (15 years ago).

The protagonist is imprisoned and repeatedly attempts to escape. He practices hiding in the guard's shadow and mimicking his movements. He eventually perfects this skill to the point where the guard fails to notice him, enabling his escape. There's a scene where the protagonist visits a house, presumably to meet an old lover. He's become so adept at hiding that he can be in the same room as the woman and her husband, undetected, and even interact with her right under the husband's nose.

Does anyone recognize this movie or have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a magical skill?  Is there anything else that makes this on-topic?

Comment: Well, not a magical skill, but it's definitely in the realm of "super human". I posted this question on another forum where someone told me to come and post it here, someone else on that forum also knew the answer and urged me to ask it here since he knew the answer. And thanks for the warm welcome :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [*3-Iron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-Iron) (2004).

> [T]he film stars Jae Hee as a young drifter who develops a relationship
> with an abused housewife (Lee Seung-yeon). The film's title is derived
> from a type of golf club used prominently throughout the narrative.

The film was marketed as a romantic drama film, so not really Scifi or Fantasy, but the scenes with the protagonist hiding in shadows are certainly written as fantastical.

> Seung Chung describes Tae-suk as "literally [becoming] invisible after
> mastering the ability to hide in the shadowy jail cell, outside the
> purview of human vision, through metaphysical 'ghost practice'"

You can see some of the shadow scenes in the video below.

Comment: A pretty cool movie. It has a special place in my heart since it was shown ages ago in one of the first iterations of the (now well established) independent film festival of my city. Kim ki-duk is a director of renown, too. I wouldn't say this is scifi/fantasy and is probably off-topic here; at best it has some touches of "magical realism".